# Pyspark Pivot table with Multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, pivot, transpose

I am trying to pivot a dataframe with one key and multiple values across different columns . How do I do this in pyspark ? I have used pivot with one key value pair before and trying to figure this out.

Sample dataframe

| id | test_id | test_status | key | score1 | score2 | score3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | complete | q1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| ABC | 1 | complete | q2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| ABC | 2 | complete | q1 | 1 | 6 | 7 |
| ABC | 2 | complete | q2 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

expected dataframe

| id | test_id | test_status | q1_score1 | q1_score2 | q1_score3 | q2_score1 | q2_score2 | q2_score3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | complete | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| ABC | 2 | complete | 1 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do multiple columns pivot.

```
df = (df.groupby('id', 'test_id', 'test_status')
      .pivot('key')
      .agg(*[F.first(x).alias(x) for x in ['score1', 'score2', 'score3']]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`pivot`** and **`first`** aggregate function.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('ABC','1','c','q1','1','2','3'),('ABC','1','c','q2','4','5','6')],['id','test_id','test_status','key','score1','score2','score3'])
df.show(10,False)
df.groupBy("id","test_id","test_status").pivot("key").agg(first(col("score1")).alias("score1"),first(col("score2")).alias("score2"),first(col("score3")).alias("score3")).show(10,False)
#input
#+---+-------+-----------+---+------+------+------+
#|id |test_id|test_status|key|score1|score2|score3|
#+---+-------+-----------+---+------+------+------+
#|ABC|1      |c          |q1 |1     |2     |3     |
#|ABC|1      |c          |q2 |4     |5     |6     |
#+---+-------+-----------+---+------+------+------+

#+---+-------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
#|id |test_id|test_status|q1_score1|q1_score2|q1_score3|q2_score1|q2_score2|q2_score3|
#+---+-------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
#|ABC|1      |c          |1        |2        |3        |4        |5        |6        |
#+---+-------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```